# Can't access SQL Server with my sa credential

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, sa

I reset my SQL Server 2008 R2 `sa` password:

```
sp_password @new = 'joomlacmssenha', @loginame = 'sa'
```

But when I try to access using SQL Server Authentication with these credentials, I get the following error:

> Connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the login process. (provider: Shared Memory Provider, error: 0 - No process is on the other end of the pipe.) (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 233)

The explanation for that error is:

> The SQL Server client cannot connect to the server. This error could occur because the server is not configured to accept remote connections.

But it is a local database, not a remote. So why is this error happening?

Comment: What name are you using to connect to the server? Have you tried forcing tcp/ip using `tcp:server name[\instance name]`? Have you verified that shared memory and tcp/ip are enabled protocols in SQL Server Configuration Manager?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution.

https://serverfault.com/questions/35505/cant-connect-to-sql-server-using-sa-account-what-im-missing

I still don´t understand why microsoft says that is a remote connection problem.

Comment: Microsoft's error message says that it ***could*** be a remote connection problem. Note that security / access error messages are deliberately vague - if someone malicious is trying to gain access to your server, how much help do you want to give them? You should be able to get more details directly in the SQL Server log (you are looking for a State # - see https://sqlblog.org/2020/07/28/troubleshooting-error-18456). What was the state # in this case?